# WebView disappears when a link is clicked

Tags: android, url, hyperlink, webview, client

I'm trying to make a WebView which receives an html from a server. That html contains both text and links. I want to make it so that the links starting with `@` open a new fragment containing the information for the said user, i.e: `@george`. However, when I click it, the WebView simply disappears.. without any sort of a log. Here's my code:

```
        client = new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, final String url) {
                if (url.startsWith("@")) {
                    final String username = url.substring(1);

                    new DataRequester(getApplicationContext()).getUserInfo(username, new Callback<User>() {
                        @Override
                        public void success(User user, Response response) {
                            ProfileFragment profileFragment = new ProfileFragment(getApplicationContext(), user);
                            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            transaction.replace(R.id.mainFrame, profileFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

                        }
                    });

                    return true;
                } else {
                    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
                }
            }
        };
```

and later:

```
    public WebView webView= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    webView.setWebViewClient(client);
    webView.loadData(notification.getHtml(), "text/html", null);
```

P.S: The problem isn't in my data request. I'm using it everywhere and it's correct.

Comment: post your `ProfileFragment ` code

Comment: @SpringBreaker It's way too long to post but it's just a regular full-screen fragment, inflating a layout. I'm calling the same data request with the same success body elsewhere as well and it's working just fine, though.